# How to view your own docker files without being root properly

Tags: linux, docker, redhat

Good afternoon I have a question that causes me concern

I am trying to enter to verify some files of the docker installation, where it is located image, containers, etc.

When I try to enter it happens to me that I must use sudo to be able to visualize the folders when being inside the docker folder:

[image]

But when I try to enter any of this folder, even with the sudo command, the file or the files as such do not appear to me, as shown below:

[image]

As you can see after executing the command sudo cd image, it doesn't return anything

How could I solve this? Should I add some kind of special permission to the user in question? Could it only be done with root user?

I would like to clarify this doubt.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: instead of `sudo cd` -- Try logging in as the sudo root user (or *superuser*) -- `sudo su`  --  Then just do `cd image` -- If that does not work, the administrator may have reduced privileges of the `sudo` user or group.  You may have to chat with your administrator.

Comment: What if I can't use anything from the root user? Should I speak to get my privileges up?

Comment: Resolvi changes the owner of the directory and the group with the command chown

Answer (score 0):

`cd` is not a program but an in-built command and sudo only applies to programs.
you are connected with a user which didn't have permission to access that directory
instead try

`sudo -i`

to elevate yourself to super user. or change directory permission or owner using root account.

Comment: Resolvi changes the owner of the directory and the group with the command chown